# PHP @var annotation for array element

Tags: php, annotations

I know that in `$Foo` and in `$array['Foo']` I have got stored the `class Bar` instance.

I expected the same result of using the `@var` annotation in both cases.

It works correctly:

```
/* @var $Foo Bar */
$Foo->| // [I see tips correctly]
```

But how to do that:

```
/* @var $array['Foo'] Bar */
$array['Foo']->| // [I want to see tips here, but nothing happens]
```

P.S. Sign `|` shows the Text Cursor position.

P.S.2. I tested this annotation on PhpStorm 7. Is not this IDE ready for this feature?

Comment: I haven't seen an IDE yet that recognizes associative values by their key.

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha Zend Studio

Comment: I'll have to check that one out.

Comment: Use local variable $foo = $array['Foo']; It will be work everywhere. This way more readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPStorm Code Hinting for array of object arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643245/phpstorm-code-hinting-for-array-of-object-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually worked for me in PhpStorm 9. Maybe you should try upgrading: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/